# .NET Core 3 MVC download a file from HTTP and re-deliver to client using minimum memory

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NET Core 3 MVC app that needs to read a file from one location over HTTP and then re-deliver it back out to the response.  Some of these files will be ~200MB in size.

What I have works, but it reads the whole file into memory before sending the `File` result out to the client.  Is there a way to make it essentially a passthrough where the read stream flows into the response stream so that very little memory is required on the server?

This is what I have now but I do not think will perform well with large files:

```
if (requestedFile != null)
{
    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        using (var result = await client.GetAsync(requestedFile.DownloadUrl))
        {
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var bytes = await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                return File(bytes, "application/zip", "largefile.zip");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried this which results in a runtime error of "Cannot access a closed Stream":

```
using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
{
    using (var httpResponseMessage = await client.GetAsync(requestedFile.DownloadUrl))
    {
        return File(await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), "application/zip", "largefile.zip");

    }
}
```

Edit:

Solution after some trial and error was remocing all using statements and letting the `FileStreamResult` close the stream on its own.  So I ended up with:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var result = await client.GetAsync(requestedFile.DownloadUrl);
var stream = await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/zip")
{
    FileDownloadName = "largefile.zip"
};
```

Comment: can you try zipping file and then stream those file ?

Comment: I edited the question a bit to reflect that some of the files being downloaded are zips, up to around 200MB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the overloads for File is a Stream. Just get that URL as a Stream or read the response body as a stream and immediately return that in the overload:

```
var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
  
var result = await client.GetAsync(requestedFile.DownloadUrl);
var stream = await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
 
return File(stream,"application/pdf", "Invoice.pdf");
```

Note: this will fail if you wrap the Stream in a using block as the FileResult already closes the Stream.

Comment: `HttpClient.ReadAsStreamAsync` is not in .NET Core 3 I think (compile error).  I tried something similar (see edit in main question), but it results in a runtime error.  It's close though...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstreamasync?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: That's the same thing I tried that resulted in the `Cannot access a closed Stream` error. But like I said in the earlier comment, I think it's close.

Comment: Try removing the using around httpclient

Comment: Removing the usings got me where I needed to go.  I didn't end up with your exact code example, but it got me where I needed to go.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, just tested it out and apparently the File Result closes the streams so there is no need to use the using block.

Answer (score 0):

For Export Excel

```
 var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            var comp = client.GetAsync($"RewardEmployee/ExportExcelCalculate?rewardConfigId={id}").Result;

`var stream = await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

 return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
            "ExportExcelCalculateRewardEmployee.xlsx");
```